# How do I use sscanf properly?

Tags: c, scanf

I believe this is the only relevant information:

```
sscanf("%d:%d:%d", zombies[i].hour, zombies[i].min, zombies[i].sec);
```

This is apparently wrong. I'm not sure why. I have tried reading the manpage, and apparently I need formatting, but I don't understand how.

Note that

- zombies[i].hour,
- zombies[i].min and
- zombies[i].sec are from an array of structures,

  the specific elements are an integers.

The compiler said I was making a pointer from an integer without a cast.

What does this mean? How do I correctly use this?

Comment: what is `zombies` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like `scanf`, you need to pass pointers that `sscanf` can use to store read values. You also have to pass a string to read the values from.

```
sscanf("1:2:3", "%d:%d:%d", &zombies[i].hour, &zombies[i].min, &zombies[i].sec);
```

If you don’t pass a pointer, you’re just passing a value, so if the current value of `zombies[i].hour` happened to be 45, for example, it’d be akin to:

```
scanf("%d", 45);
```

which makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier! Thanks!

Comment: Another good practice if seeking to *"use sscanf properly"* per the question title is - if there's any way this could fail to parse - to compare the `sscanf` return value to the number of conversions expected: `if (sscanf(...) == 3) ...use parsed values... else ...report/handle error...;`